# Different font (size) for text in images from Inkscape to Latex

Tags: latex, inkscape

I am using Inkscape to convert images to Latex, so the text scales nicely. Using SaveAs pdf, with generate Latex ticked.
This creates a .pdf_tex file that contains something like this:

```
\begingroup%
\begin{picture}(1,1.18884212)%   
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{Scapula.pdf}}%  
\put(0.6981335,0.82053681){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Infraspinous fossa}}}%
\end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

I would like to change the font size and possible also the font, so the text in all images is different from the body text. I think this is possible by e.g. redefining \smash within "picture", but I don't know how. Is this the correct approach? If so, any tips on how to do it?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this was possible, I don't think LaTeX can modify PDFs (it's just a markup language after all). Why not just define the font size and style in Inkscape?

Comment: The PDF contains no text or leaders. To my understanding, the generated Latex code (the included example) overlay text at defined positions which match the background image. I can easily add formatting directly to the code, but I would like to do this global, for all pictures.

Answer (score 1):

With the `etoolbox` you could add the fontsize change to the `picture` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{picture}{\huge}


\begin{document}

\begingroup%
\begin{picture}(1,1.18884212)%   
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{example-image.pdf}}%  
\put(0.6981335,0.82053681){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Infraspinous fossa}}}%
\end{picture}%
\endgroup%


\end{document}
```